ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg in psycopg2
I'm having trouble importing the psycopg2 module in Python. When I try to import psycopg2, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 import psycopg2

File c:\Users\ricardo.torres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py:51
      1 """A Python driver for PostgreSQL
      2 
      3 psycopg is a PostgreSQL_ database adapter for the Python_ programming
   (...)
     17     TimeFromTicks, Timestamp, TimestampFromTicks
     18 """
     19 # psycopg/__init__.py - initialization of the psycopg module
     20 #
     21 # Copyright (C) 2003-2019 Federico Di Gregorio  <fog@debian.org>
   (...)
     48 
     49 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
---> 51 from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
     52     BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID,
     53 
     54     Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp,
     55     DateFromTicks, TimeFromTicks, TimestampFromTicks,
     56 
     57     Error, Warning, DataError, DatabaseError, ProgrammingError, IntegrityError,
     58     InterfaceError, InternalError, NotSupportedError, OperationalError,
     59 
     60     _connect, apilevel, threadsafety, paramstyle,
     61     __version__, __libpq_version__,
     62 )
     65 # Register default adapters.
     67 from psycopg2 import extensions as _ext

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.


I’m using Windows and have downloaded and installed PostgreSQL successfully.

I've tried reinstalling the library with pip install psycopg2 and also with pip install psycopg2-binary.
I installed psycopg2 using a simple pip install psycopg2 command. I also tried pip install psycopg2-binary to see if it would make a difference, but the error remains.



python 3.13 could be one culprit. with a bit of googling i found this: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1692

I'm not an expert but I downloaded an older version of python and the problem was solved. Thank you very much for your comment.
